# Insert country official language based on a country name in a column

Tags: scripting

I have a form that feeds a spreadsheet (from "jotforms", not google form) and I have in column D a list of Countries (only country name) and I need to insert the official language somewhow for each country in another Column (lets say column U) on form submission. (meaning each time a new row is added).

I need the language to be displayed full text, not codes like "fr, spa, eng, etc." I want it to say English, Spanish, French, etc. Full words.
I Need the script or formula to work only in the sheet "Members Registration".

Is this possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can think of two ways to do this.

In Jotform, make one empty hidden question that will be the Language column in your Google Sheet. Then make one hidden read-only question per language, with the full language name as the default value.

Lastly, in Settings make a Conditional action; if the country selection is this or that, copy value from the right language holder to the empty Language question. Language column is then filled out automatically depending on country choice.

---

The other way would be to add a column in your gsheet for Language and use a `VLOOKUP` formula on the whole column to a new tab in your gsheet. If your country code is in column D and the country-to-language reference is in Tab2, use:

```
If(isblank(D2),"",vlookup(D2, Tab2!A:B,2))
```

The formula column won't be cleared by new form submissions.

Comment: The suggestion #1 is unpractical for me. If I wanted to type hundreds of languages by myself I would just do it manually in my sheet. I was looking for a way to avoid doing that. 

Your suggestion #2 is more appealing, but I don't quiet understand it. Could you show it to me by doing it directly in my spreadsheet? 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O4MuWkgMnfr29MvG4by_-zofUGSaTqh6Sh5R1jEKFLI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok I think I have made your suggestion #2 work. I had to figure out how to make it work.. So thanks!!

Comment: Great, my pleasure!

Comment: Also look into zapier.com, its like IFTT.com. Its good for lookup lists and parsing.